# Subtract hours with values obtained in NSTextField

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have the code below that takes the current time in one `NSTextField` and the reference time in another `NSTextField`

```
let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Amsterdam")        
let dateFormatter = NSDate()
let hora = dateFormatter.date(withCalendarFormat: lblLastClick.stringValue, timeZone: timeZone)
let horaAtual = dateFormatter.date(withCalendarFormat: lblClock.stringValue, timeZone: timeZone)
```

What I need is to subtract the reference time from the current time and see how many minutes have passed, I can not get it to work, I've already tried it in many ways.

Comment: Can you give some sample values for `lblLastClick` and `lblClock `?

Answer (score 0):

```
let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: date)

        let strYear = String(difference.year!)
        let strMonth = "-" + String(difference.month!)
        let strDays = "-" + String(difference.day!)
        let strHours = String(difference.hour!)
        let strMinit = ":" + String(difference.minute!)
        let strSec = ":" + String(difference.second!)
```

Comment: `let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: hora as Date, to: horaAtual as Date)` print only :0

Comment: @Rene yes, you rock.

Comment: ohk just a minit